# UWP webview video element not shown

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp

In Xamarin.Forms 4.6.0.800, video element in UWP Webview is not shown at all.
The video element is

```
<video preload="metadata" controls="true" controlsList="nodownload" height="160px" width="120px" poster="poster.png" src="https://somewebsite/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Xamarin.Forms 4.6.0.800, video element in UWP Webview is not shown at all.

I have tested with [official](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithwebview/) code sample and updated the nuget to latest version, and video tag works as excepted. please check if the video source is available. the following is my html content.

```
<video width="320" 
       height="240" 
       controls 
       src="mp4 file url"
       type="video/mp4">       
</video>
```